# Dynamic “merge & Center” rows based on date values using “Conditional Formating”

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-365

My question is really similar to the one presented here: 
[Excel do dynamic "merge & Center" based on values or through "Conditional Formating"](https://superuser.com/questions/281521/excel-do-dynamic-merge-center-based-on-values-or-through-conditional-format)

but in this case I want this in **rows structure**:)

[image]

Row Number 1 contains Dates
and in Row Number 2 I'd like to have the Name or number of Month showcased in the middle of each month duration (or approx on day 15). 
Instead of doing this the hard way (manually) using "merge and center", I want to have a dynamic system using conditional formatting.

User adamV (https://superuser.com/users/15903/adamv) gave a great answer on how to do this in columns. It would be much appreciated if you could help me with the formulas needed to do this in rows structure this time.

Thank you so very much : )

Comment: Please note that this isn't a free script writing service, we expect users to attempt their own solution first and ask specific questions

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant one, but serves the purpose.

If you are content with

1. Putting single letter of the month in different cells (using `MID` function)
2. Not exactly centered letter sequences for some months.
3. An unmerged solution. (is better from the bright side)

Here is my **VBA-free** solution idea.

Let's assume you are using the format `"mmm-yy"` that has 6 characters, say `Jan-20`. You can put `J` to the `13th` day, a to the `14th, ..., 0` to the `18th` day and use `""` for the rest, i.e.

As illustrated in the figure: `IF(AND(DAY(Q2)>12;DAY(Q2)<19);MID(TEXT(Q2;"aaa-yy");DAY(Q2)-12;1);"")`

Month info written between `13-to-18th` days with single `letter/number` per cell

[image]

I have elaborated the problem further and shown the week number to be written (almost) in the middle of seven cells making up a week.

To accomplish this, I have created strings containing the week number and three leading spaces if the week number is either one or two digits, two leading spaces if the week number is more than two digits through

```
REPT(" ";3-INT(LOG(L4;100)))&TEXT(L4;"###")
```

Where week numbers of the dates are obtained in a helper row, that is the `4th` row here. And at the fifth row, weekdays are extracted from the dates to use in `MID` formula.

Optionally, these numbers obtained as strings can be converted back to numeral values.

Final form of the formula has become:

```
MID(   REPT(" ";3-INT(LOG(L4;100)))&TEXT(L4;"###")   ;L5;1)
```

As illustrated in: Week numbers written as one digit per cell (almost) at the center of each week

[image]

Then, you can use conditional formatting to create visual aids to divide the table into regions.

In the file shared below, a global start and finish date is also added so that one can change the table dynamically as long as the formulas in the rows are copied to enough number of columns. (4 months are covered in the example file)

Note, at a point it is very frustrating to avoid local settings in programs. Therefore, illustrations contain Turkish names of the months `Ocak` is `January`, `Şubat` is `February` in Turkish.

And here is the example worksheet file.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: you are very wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

After tying this off, a thought occurred to me. Duh. You could use formulas to get the desired result in the desired cells, and instead of the knee-jerk reaction of ending the `IF()`'s used here with "" to display empty cells, make all the failures have a result of "MMM" (I used to figure "KKK" was best because I would NEVER encounter it as a real entry in my spreadsheets, so I'd never have to worry the following would hammer something, but then my boss shared a spreadsheet with somebody and... the fan sprayed stuff all over... now I use "MMM" for this!)

THEN, copy the entire row, every last cell, and Paste|Special|Values so now you have about 30 cells with "MMM" for each month and one each month with the right result. Finally, use `Find and Replace` to replace all those "MMM" entries with an empty cell. Now, since there are no values in any of the cells except the right ones, their strings can spill left and right as needed to properly display as you desire. (Be sure to format them to center in the cell so they spill both directions and it all still looks nicely centered on each month.

Jeez... I keep recommending the easy handwork (below) since the low-tech method is not always to be sneered at, lots of times is much easier. And forgot altogether an old favorite of mine. Maybe because I usually associate it with data work, but that's no excuse for simulating senility.

So, the formula should test for whether it is February or not, yielding a result in the cell below the 15th of the month if not February (not the 16th sometimes because in your toher question you made mention that you expected the 15th whereas one might think "centered' suggests the 16th for 31 day months), and for February, it should simply test for how many days in month (leap years will report 29, so that catches them without an involved test), and if 28, put the result in the cell under the 14th, and for 29, put it in the cell under the 15th. That's it, then copy and Paste|Special|Values, and finish with `Find and
Replace` to empty the cells that have "MMM" and you're done.

Use a formula like:

```
=IF(  MONTH(A1)=2,  IF(  DAY(  EOMONTH(A1,0)  )=29,  IF(  DAY(A1)=15,  TEXT(A1,"Mmm-yy"),"MMM"),  IF(  DAY(A1)=14,  TEXT(A1,"Mmm-yy"),  "MMM")),  IF(  DAY(A1)=15,  TEXT(A1,"Mmm-yy"),  "MMM"))
```

(I put sets of two spaces in here and there for ease of following the working. `Find and Replace` two spaces with nothing at all to remove them.)

This tests for month = 2 (Febraury) and if it is, then it uses `EOMONTH()` with a "0" for how many months so it is checking the "current" month, so to speak. If it is 29 (a leap year, then it tests for the date being the 15th giving the desired result if so and "MMM" if not, then quits. If it failed the 29 idea, it checks the Day for being the 14th and does the same thing. Finally, if the month was not 2, it skips all that and goes to the last bit, testing for Day=15.

One COULD likely be slick and cut that down a hair by using `AND()` with clever grouping of tests, but... it's not like it will be used down 300,000 rows and slow the spreadsheet down forever! No more than 16384 columns, eh? And then turned to constants, not formulas, and 29/20's of those cleared away. So it's fine like it is. Another possible improvement could be to test if the month is NOT 2 and have the final clause right there, then go on to testing for it being Month 2. That would make the formula clearer, by, um, really anyone's measure...

The below is still all true and might help someone someday so I shall leave it.

The basic issue is that you have to put a formula into a cell in the row in question in order to test if it is the right cell to show output. But that means testing them all if you don't want to do the handwork in a different guise.

Note that you could do the handwork for one year (put a formula that shows the month-year as desired, center it in the cell so it spills left and right as needed to show its full text, just the one formula per month where it needs to be, and just copy and paste three more, adjust the one with the leap year, then copy those four years worth of cells and paste under the next four years in row 1, rinse, and repeat, or be slicker and copy those eight years, then paste, copy the 16 yearrs and paste... fill up a sh*t-ton of years realllllllly fast.

Moving on though, as you want something with no handwork. WHY does it matter that all the cells in row 2 have formulas testing to see if they get to be the real boy for the month? Because the result in the one that wins cannot spill left and right out of its own cell if the cells left and right are occupied. And the columns are too narrow to show the full "Jan-20"... unless you'd like to widen them. So you might see "n-2" or "an-2" or whatever, but not the full text.

Without the formulas in EVERY cell, you can't automatically get the result in the proper cell. But WITH them in every cell (and the width limitation row 1 seems built to permit), you can't get the full output of the right one displayed. Formulas cannot help you.

You know, unless that teensy bit of handwork, five minutes maybe, that I described would be ok after all.

So you have to have a macro do it. The macro can start in A1 and test the value, decide the month it is, figure how many days in the month, divide by two and round down to get 15 for EVERY month except February (except for the leap years (divisible by four, so February can be asily tested each time it rolls up, at least until 2400))...

So the macro can basically test the DAY of each month instead, or test  one, then follow a pattern you give it, cycling through 12 months (start month doesn't matter, they still come in cycles of 12 April to March or whatever), putting the desired values or even formulas for them so you don't even have to make out a list of values into the cell for the 15th of every month except Febraury. Then it can quickly run back through testing for leap years and moving February's to the 15th as well... or... once it has the first leap year, it can just move right 1,460 cells or so, delete the 14th's entry, move right and enter it in the 15th's, then jump again, etc.

Even with mild VBA skills you should be able to write that. And the handwork that does the same is five minutes, tops.

Comment: While it's great you've put a huge amount of effort answering this question, it's very difficult to read. Would be great to asks create a shorter summary of your solution

Comment: @Jeorje Indeed thanks so much for all the hard effort. I have to admit I'm not that much of an expert in excel formulas. It would be really great if you could share the excel file that you worked on or just point out the steps for dummies like myself. But really, thanks again!